# SQLite - remove all spaces

Tags: sql, sqlite

Is there any way to remove all spaces using SQLite, kind of global `trim()`, not using any scripting language? I'm trying to hash values from multiple columns to track any changes but that will require to remove spaces for columns with multiple strings.

So far I wasn't able to find any tip related to that topic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

SQLite has some built-in string functions, including trim().

```
select trim(mycolumn) from mytable;
```

If you're trying to delete all spaces, you can use replace().

```
select replace(mycolumn, ' ', '') from mytable;
```

If you are trying to combine several columns you can use this with the concatenate operator.

```
select trim(col1) || trim(col2) || trim(col3) from mytable;
```

Comment: As an additional note: If the spaces are in the form of tabs, then `trim` does not really work. The second method here with `replace` worked for me where I explicitly put a tab in the second argument.

Answer (score 0):

if you mean remove extra spaces

```
trim(replace(replace(replace(mycolumn, ' ', '| '),  ' |',''), '|',''))
```